# How to get new node into firebase from android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to add a new node to the selected vehicle from the list. If I enter the vehicle id manually in the code, then it is added correctly, but if I add veriable auto_id in the same place, then the method does not execute correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACSRV.png)

My Firebase and Rules:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJxZ9.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMhzK.png)

I was looking for solutions on Stackoverflow and YouTube but unfortunately none of them worked.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do not show pictures of code.  Please edit the question and copy the code directly into it, and format it, so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: What is the expected result? Please respond with @AlexMamo